# 'npm run test' works, but 'jest --coverage' command does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jestjs, lerna

I have MonoRepo project (using [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna)) which consists of multiple packages, and one of them is a React application.

Within the React project package, I utilise Jest for unit testing. However, when I run the `jest --coverage` command on the WebStorm console, it returns me the following error:

> zsh: command not found: jest

Strangely enough, if I use `npm run test`, the test runs, and my test coverage report is generated. Here is part of my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --coverage",
  // other stuff
},
```

As you can see, `npm run test` runs `jest --coverage`, which is the exact command I initially entered. Why won't the `jest` command work on its own?

Comment: `jest` isn't installed globally, I'd guess. try `./node_modules/.bin/jest`; that's where NPM puts the executables, and what it adds to the path when running your `"scripts"`.

Comment: `$ npx jest` is a simpler shortcut instead of `$ ./node_modules/.bin/jest`

Comment: `npx` is available from NPM 5.2.0 - https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe!

Comment: if you instead do `lerna run test` from the root does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it directly from your `node_modules` like this:

`./node_modules/.bin/jest --coverage`

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#running-from-command-line for more information

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution is to install jest globally with:

```
npm i -g jest
```